# What technique or tools should I use to make frosting in this particular shape?

Tags: cake, frosting

I want to make dessert like in the screenshot. How can I make the white part to look the same in real life as in the screenshot (it could be not rounded corners, if it will be impossible)? The consistency is something like frosting. The brown is a dough almost like a muffin.

I can't just pour it on, because there will be drips. I also thought I could make the dough and dip it in the frosting, but then there would be peaks on top when it all dried out. Is there any other way to do it?

[image]

Comment: fondant is usually how very flat and smooth icing is achieved

Comment: Off the cuff I have at least three ideas how this could be done  - can you explain what kind of experience and expertise you have? Frankly, that picture is about as nondescript as it can be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would wrap the lower part in something, plastic foil is probably best because it is slightly elastic and can be stuck together to be tight. You can try lightly oiling the inside of the plastic wrap, so that it might not stick to the cake itself too much and possibly rip off some of the surface. Make sure the cake has fully cooled first.

Then drop or spread the glaze on top, let it set, then cut it away using a knife or spatula, then remove the plastic. If the glaze is soft enough, you should be able to pull it off by simply removing the plastic. If the glaze is very gelatinous, be careful not to tear it during the removal.

If you don't want to have to pull anything off the cake, you could make a thick paper or thin cardboard 'collar', like a cat's medical collar preventing him from licking and biting himself. The narrow opening should be at the top just where you want the frosting to end, taped together there. Make sure is tight enough that no glaze could leak between cake and collar (although a tiny bit of leakage is probably fairly easy to clean up later).

Comment: Yes, great idea. I would suggest to apply some **non-stick spray** on the foil just before wrapping the cake, so it does not tear off the surface when taking the plastic off

Comment: @Marck: Good idea, though I don't remember ever seeing such a substance for sale here in supermarkets.

Comment: yeah, same here. I believe it's more available in the US (at least this is what I concluded from the videos I am watching). Otherwise, I would suggest to butter the foil like we would do with a cake mold, or maybe spread a thin layer of tasteless vegetal oil.

Comment: @Marck: Right, that is a good idea. I'm not sure how well that will work, but it's certainly worth a try, I'll add it to my answer. I've also added a bit about a cat collar.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend preparing a frosting which has the consistency of heavy whipped cream, or the consistency of a very well made chocolate mousse: incorporate a lot of air, it's one of the secrets. Then, put your cake on a plate and grab a spatula, spread your frosting on top and on the edges, like you want. The frosting's consistency is crucial here: you **must** be able to spread it evenly (without any lumps popping on the surface), but it is also important that it is not too liquid, or the frosting will drip on the edges.

Note that you can always do a cleanup of the edges after the operation, with a clean spatula and/or some paper towel.

Here are some links for methods/recipes:

- [Binging with Babish's chocolate cake](https://www.bingingwithbabish.com/recipes/2017/6/6/chocolate-cake-inspired-by-matilda?rq=frost)
- [Binging with Babish's angel cake](https://www.bingingwithbabish.com/recipes/angel-food-cake-groundhog-day?rq=frost)
- [Joshua Weissman's chocolate cake](https://www.joshuaweissman.com/post/chocolate-cake)
- [Jushua Weissman's carrot cake](https://www.joshuaweissman.com/post/homemade-carrot-cake)